# Sending LUKs encrypted USB drive to cloud storage

Tags: usb-drive, remote, luks

I have a LUKs encrypted USB drive. 
I want to send the image of the encrypted drive to remote site
I want to be able to pull this encrypted image and flash it back onto a new USB drive.
Using same passphrase, new USB should be able to be mounted and read.

I am investigating dd command.

Comment: You can do exactly what you said, image and restore. It shouldn't matter if it's encrypted as you will be copying byte for byte. Do you have a question or problem?

Comment: `dd` will work just fine. Though I recommend including a checksum (ex. sha256) if your image. Alternatively, you can create an image of the unlocked block device using `partclone`. Such an image would be smaller than one created with `dd`, but you'd have to encrypt it and then also recreate the LUKS container when restoring the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very easily.

```
dd if=/dev/sdX of=my_image.img bs=1M status=progress
```

This will save a full disk image of your USB drive to `my_image.img`, make sure to replace `sdX` with your actual device name.

You can then save `my_image.img` wherever you want. To restore simply do the same in reverse:

```
dd if=my_image.img of=/dev/sdX bs=1M status=progress
```

Make sure not to select the wrong device. Triple check.